# how to convert a method type to a type that can be multiplied: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'method' and 'Piecewise'

Tags: python, methods, types, typeerror, sympy

i have a problem that i need to multiply the type {method} and a piecewise function, all in symbolic sympy.

i try to multiply a Piecewise expression with Derivative of another expression that. the result of the Derivative expression is from a type 'method'
here is my code:

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt  # This is all the library's i need
import mpmath
n = 10
x = sp.symbols('x', positive=True)
c = list(sp.symbols('c0:%d'%(n + 1)))
f = 1+(((sp.exp(x) * (1 - np.exp(-1))) + (sp.exp(-x)) * (np.exp(1) - 1)) / (np.exp(-1) - np.exp(1)))
xx = np.linspace(0, 1, n + 1)
i = 0
N = []
a = sp.Piecewise(
                 (((xx[i + 1] - x) / (xx[i + 1] - xx[i])), (x >= float((xx[i]))) and x <= float((xx[i + 1]))),
                 (0, x > float(xx[i + 1])),
)
N.append(a)
for i in range(1, n):
    a = sp.Piecewise(
        (0, x < float(xx[i - 1])),
        ((xx[i - 1] - x) / (xx[i - 1] - xx[i]), ((x >= float((xx[i - 1]))) & (x <= float(xx[i])))),
        ((xx[i + 1] - x) / (xx[i + 1] - xx[i]), ((x >= float(xx[i])) & (x <= float(xx[i + 1])))),
        (0, x > float(xx[i + 1])),
        (0, True),
    )
    N.append(a)
i = i + 1
a = sp.Piecewise(
    (0, x < float(xx[i - 1])),
    ((xx[i - 1] - x) / (xx[i - 1] - xx[i]), ((x >= float((xx[i - 1]))) & (x <= float(xx[i])))),
    (0, True),
)
N.append(a)
k = []
#u = []
for i in range(0, n + 1):
    if i == 0:
     u = c[i] * N[i]
    else:
     u = c[i] * N[i] +u
Ntag = []
for i in range(0, n + 1):
    tag = N[i].diff(x)
    Ntag.append(tag)
utag = u.diff
try:
 res= utag*Ntag[i]# for any integer
except:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

and the output is:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'method' and 'Piecewise'

and the line that making the error is the last line:
utag*Ntag[i]

and the traceback is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".py", line 56, in <module>
    res= utag*Ntag[i]# for any integer
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'method' and 'Piecewise'
```

Comment: You need to show the _full stacktrace_. Just the error alone is almost pointless. The stacktrace shows which line caused the error. Otherwise you're making us guess which of the dozens of lines could be causing the error. That's way too much effort to expect of us.

Comment: Ugh. That stacktrace is from some awful IDE or notebook-like thing that just execs the code piecemeal, hiding line info completely. Is there any way you can run this as a plain script, to get a useful traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay well the mistake is obvious. `u.diff` is clearly a function, not a number; but it's not being called like a function. The function itself is being assigned to `utag`. So, you're trying to multiply the function `u.diff` with the value `Ntag[i]`. But `u.diff` is not a numerical value, it is just a function. You'd have to *call* the function if you wanted it to return an actual value. But you're not calling it, you're just referencing it.

Comment: i am sorry but i didn't understand why. because Ntag[i] is also a function

Comment: Pedantic: It's a *method* (or more generally, a callable). Specifically, `u.diff` is a bound method which packages `u` (the object) with the underlying function (sometimes called an unbound method since it's attached to a class for binding) attached to `u`'s class (`diff`). That's why the error is complaining about a method (if it were a true function/unbound method that behaves like a function, it would say so).

Comment: @OrMilo so if `Ntag[i]` actually refers to a function (which I highly doubt), but you are not calling the function like `Ntag[i]()`, why would you expect to be able to use the `*` operator on a function directly? Assuming that was even true, you're just confirming that your code is in fact very broken without explaining why you made any of your choices.

Comment: @OrMilo: How so? `Ntag[i]` appears to be the result of *calling* a method (`N[i].diff`, called with `N[i].diff(x)`), not the method itself.

Comment: you are right i am sorry its not a function its an expression. Ntag[] is a list of derivatives of a list of piecewise function

Comment: So, you have shown that you know that you have to actually _call_ `N[i].diff(x)`. Yet for `u`, you're just trying to multiply by the method `u.diff` rather than actually calling `u.diff(x)` (or whatever needs to go in place of `x`). I don't get how you simultaneously are doing those two different things without realizing your mistake. You know how to do it right, and you're actually doing it right elsewhere in the code, so to make that error in the first place, and be confused by it - I'm confused by your confusion. Did you even write all this or is it copied from elsewhere to some degree?